# Change live Wallpaper on Rooted Device Android

Tags: android

Since it's not possible to change live wallpaper programmatically on Android, is it somehow possible to change live wallpaper if the device is rooted?

I am working on an Application that her purpose is to choose from all of the installed live wallpapers on the Device and to set it on the Androids Home background. But the thing is that I need to do that strictly programmatically without any user interaction.

Can some one help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

maybe XDA can help on this:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=684557

other than this , you can check the code of the liveWallpaperChoose and see how it changes the live wallpaper .

using the normal API (starting with jelly bean) , you select the live wallpaper and all the user needs is to confirm selecting it:

[How do I move to Live Wallpaper preview from app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842924/how-do-i-move-to-live-wallpaper-preview-from-app)

Comment: this is for changing Wallpapers, and not Live Wallpapers :( The closest I was to change Live Wallpaper is by setting it in preview mode. Never mind. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: you are correct. was sure that it could do it . however , i think it's best to ask it there . xda is a perfect place for root operations and hacks . if they have an answer, please post it here too . quite an interesting question ... :)